# Wpf Prism How to set WindowStartupLocation of Custom Popup Window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I've successfully implemented Custom Popup Window by using Prism interactivity feature with this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921081(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec7).

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CustomPopupViewRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction>
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <local:PurchasePaymentInfoView />
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But the Popup Window is displayed at random position on the screen. I want to define `WindowStartupLocation` to `CenterScreen` of this Popup Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest pre-release you can use the `WindowStartupLocation` property.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Interactivity/PopupWindowAction.cs#L50

If you are not, and using the current `CenterOverAssociatedObject` property will not meet your needs:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Interactivity/PopupWindowAction.cs#L40

Then you will have to create your own `PopupWindowAction`.

Comment: Then, I will wait Prism next release.

Comment: I think you want to update your links because the code has been changed. specially the second one.

Comment: Also putting some explanation example is not bad idea `<prism:PopupWindowAction WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">`

Comment: third, I think the `WindowsStartupLocation` property, is now released and it passed the `pre-released` stage.